# Bootstrap 4 - Achieve flex + justify-content-center with 2 elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

With utilising `d-flex`, `justify-content-center` and `flew-grow-1`, I achieved the desired result with 3 divs.

```
<div class="row bg-primary d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-auto">
      LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto flex-grow-1 text-center">
      Middle
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
      Right
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to achieve the same effect with 2 divs while Middle one is forced to be the exact center. However, if I try to remove the 'Right' element, it can't calculate the center.

```
<div class="row bg-primary d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-auto">
      LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto flex-grow-1 text-center">
      Middle
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Is there a way to force "Middle" to be exact center and Left or Right divs take space from Middle as they need? *Kind of like all the positions of Left and Middle are same as in the first image but 'Right' div is not there.*

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4a7tLf0m/

---

I can achieve the same effect with giving specified column size (`col-3` instead of `col-auto`) but I don't like the fact that I need to be explicit. Is this the only way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the right/left div as `invisible` when not required. That way middle will always occupy the exact same position as when the other 2 divs are not there.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row bg-primary d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto flex-grow-1 text-center">
      Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <div class="row bg-primary d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto flex-grow-1 text-center">
      Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto invisible">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <div class="row bg-primary d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto invisible">
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto flex-grow-1 text-center">
      Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty neat solution

Comment: Thanks @Senty  :)

Comment: But if the text grows in the right or left it will not remain in the middle by doing in that way so @Senty are you sure that your text will remain the same.

Comment: @Aditi Oh actually you are right..

Comment: FYI I just want to explain why it's not working with justify-content-center, col-auto, flex-grow-1. As col-auto only expands up to the width covered by text. For the second div on which justify-content-center and flex-grow-1 is applied centers the text only within the available width excluding the width covered by first div.

Comment: @senty This is why you should use `col` instead of `col-auto` as explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553357/171456).

Comment: Is there any clean alternative to perform the same OP task without requiring the right `div` to exist (for BS 5)? Recently reached same goal. Maybe playing with `.me-auto` and `.ms-auto` or the like (mentioned in Bootstrap Flex docs), which couldn't solve it per recent attempts.